# JavaScript window.find doesn't work absolutely

Tags: javascript, find

When I try to pass text which spreads throughout a few block elements the window.find method dosent work:

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
<body>
  <p>search me</p><b> I could be the answer</b>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
window.find("meI could be");
```

Or:

```
str = "me";
str+= "\n";
str+="I could be t";

window.find(str);
```

This happens when the `<p>` element is present between the search term.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Works fine in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gt38u/1/) (well in chrome anyway)

Comment: @Musa, not in Firefox... (I neeed it to work at least with chrome, ff, safari and explorer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As option:

```
function containsStr(str) {
    return document.body.innerText.indexOf(str) > -1;
}
```

Just tested it and it's working same as window.find. Or window.find is working same as this my function.
Anyway seems it's depends to element's style.display property.
E.g. when I set

```
p {
    display: inline;
}
```

this call `window.find("me I could be")​` returns `true` for your HTML example.

I created [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/vE47D/) to test mentioned behavior.
As option you can create a `div` element in memory, get document.body.innerHTML and set retrieved value to div's `innerHTML`, then change `style.dysplay` to `"inline"` for elements within this `div` similar to what I did in my code example, and then perform a search.

**UPDATE #1: jQuery**

I've made deeper research and found that usage of jQuery `:contains` selector is working better than my previous function and than window.find, but may be more expensive (not sure, need to be tested).

```
function containsStr$(str) {
    return $('body:contains("'+str+'")').length > 0;
}
```

**UPDATE #2: pure JavaScript solution**

```
function _find(str) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
    var elements = div.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for(var i = elements.length; 0 > i--;) {
        elements[i].style.display = 'inline';
    }
    return (div.innerText || div.textContent).indexOf(str) > -1;
}
```

Comment: Did it work in firefox? (and I can't change the dom, e.g. changing elements to inline)

Comment: Good question. I've just updated my code exmaple (http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/vE47D) to make it working in FF. Also seems window.find is working somehow weird (try to click "Inline" button several times), but my function is working as expected....

Comment: This is the log I get in ff:                                       containsStr(str): true
window.find(str): false

Comment: Same for me. I've just updated the code example and my answer - seems jQuery `:contains` makes a trick. :)

Comment: Can you provide a solution without jQuery?

Comment: Just added one more function `_find(str)` that, seems, is working well.
Can you clarify your last comment about what you want to select, where and how? Or make new question at the StackOverflow since really these two questions are different.

Comment: Ok, I'll make another question... I just thought that the find method was already clear...

Comment: Here is my new question, tell me if it is more clear:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445579/javascript-window-find-does-not-select-search-term

Comment: Worked as of 2019 Sept