# How to display Find dialog in a WebView2 control?

Tags: javascript, c++, microsoft-edge, webview2

I have got an old C++ MFC app upgraded to use the WebView2 web browser control, based on Edge. Otherwise I have got it working fine, one of the remaining issues is opening the Find dialog in it via the main MFC app Edit-Find menu item or via Ctrl+F (which is also intercepted by MFC framework). What I have now is:

`m_webView->ExecuteScript(L"window.find(\"\", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);");`

where `m_webView` is a pointer to `ICoreWebView2` interface.

The problem is that sometimes it does bring up the Find dialog, sometimes not. Sometimes it does it after page refresh, sometimes not. When I close the Find dialog from cross, it typically refuses to open it again.

How can I make it behave properly? Maybe there is a way which does not need to go through Javascript?

Update: it appears it only worked if the Ctrl+F keystroke was somehow sent directly to the WebView2 control, bypassing MFC. It looks like the above Javascript line never worked. So maybe there is a way to simulate Ctrl+F for the WebView2 control?

Comment: Sounds like a focus control issue - whichever control in MFC that was last focused get's the Ctrl+F sequence.

Comment: Right, this was mostly a focus issue, the GotFocus event handler sometimes moved the focus away from the webview2 control. Still there seems no way to put the Edit-Find menu item to work. Yes I know menus are out of fashion currently...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, WebView2 currently has no support for you invoking or otherwise controlling the find in page dialog. You can also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62993052/search-functionality-in-webview2). There is [a similar thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/749) in GitHub and the official hasn't given a solution.

You can use Ctrl+F keystroke directly in WebView2 control or provide feedback about this issue on [WebView2 Feedback page](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues). Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As @yu-zhou answered, there is no official way yet to do what I wanted. For now I resorted back for emulating Ctrl+F programmatically for the WebView2 control, but the result ain't so pretty. For the record I still present it here:

First, the user has to click in the webview2 control at least once, so I can record its HWND in the GotFocus event handler registered by add_GotFocus():

```
void MyHtmlView::OnGotFocus() {
    if (!m_webview2_hwnd) {
        m_webview2_hwnd = ::GetFocus();
    }
}
```

Now, when I want to bring up the Find bar programmatically, I need to ensure the correct window is focused and send it the Ctrl+F key. Alas, it appears the control checks the Ctrl key state in async way, so it gets a bit tricky, I need to alter the keyboard state for the thread and add an extra event handler for restoring it afterwards. After some trial and error I reached this (error checks omitted for brevity):

```
void MyHtmlView::Find() {

    if (::GetFocus()!=m_webview2_hwnd) {
        ::SetFocus(m_webview2_hwnd);
    }

    std::uint8_t state[256];
    ::GetKeyboardState(state);
    bool restoreCtrlState = false;
    if ((state[VK_CONTROL] & 0x80)==0) {
        // Ctrl key is currently not pressed.
        // Mark it pressed.
        state[VK_CONTROL] |= 0x80;
        ::SetKeyboardState(state);
        restoreCtrlState = true;
    }

    std::thread auxThread([this, restoreCtrlState]() {
        ::SendMessage(m_webview2_hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, 'F', 1);
        ::SendMessage(m_webview2_hwnd, WM_KEYUP, 'F', 1);
        if (restoreCtrlState) {
            ::PostMessage(m_hWnd, WM_COMMAND, ID_RESTORE_CONTROL_STATE, 0);
        }
    });
    auxThread.detach();
}

// This needs to be registered to handle ID_RESTORE_CONTROL_STATE
void HtmlView::OnRestoreCtrlState() {
    std::uint8_t state[256];
    ::GetKeyboardState(state);
    if ((state[VK_CONTROL] & 0x80)!=0) {
        state[VK_CONTROL] &= ~0x80;
        ::SetKeyboardState(state);
    }
}
```

Needless to say, this hack may easily cease to work if they change something in the webview2 implementation.