# Does window.find() work across <p> elements or line breaks?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use [`window.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find) in JavaScript to find and select text across elements. Overall it works as expected, except across `<p>` elements (or line breaks?).

Here's my simplified HTML:

```js
findText("first with style");   // true
findText("second");             // true
findText("third");              // true
findText("second\nthird");      // false
findText("second\n\nthird");    // false
findText("second\rthird");      // false
findText("second\r\nthird");    // false
findText("second<br>third");    // false
findText("second</p><p>third"); // false
findText("second&#10;third");   // false


function findText(needle) {
  console.log(window.find(needle));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{ max-height:75px !important; }
```

```html
<p>first<b> with style</b></p>
<p>second</p>
<p>third</p>
```

Here's a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ektoguy8/2/).

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you aware that `window.find()` is non-standard? [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find).

Comment: @GregL Indeed - but I'm not aware of a suitable replacement?

Comment: Are you able to perform such a multiline search on the native search functionality of your browser? I'm not, in any of mine. `find()` is supposed to offer the same feature as the native one.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes I tried that as well but it didn't work – if your statement "_find() is supposed to offer the same feature as the native one_" is correct, then that might very well be my answer!

Comment: Do you also want the selection to happen or just to find if the text exists?

Comment: @Kaiido – Yes, I'd like to both find and select the searched text (although I don't necessarily need to use the browser's select method, I could very well surround the text with a <span> to highlight it)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any browser allows doing multiline search with their native search feature, so it's normal the DOM API doesn't either, since it's supposed to more or less mirror that feature.

If all you want to do is to check if the given text is present in the current visible text, you can get the document's [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) which will return only the visible text (here "visible" means the ones that are rendered, not necessarily the ones that are in screen).

```js
const text = document.documentElement.innerText;
const toFind = "orci.\n\nPhasellus"; // end of first paragraph + start of second.

console.log(text.includes(toFind));
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed malesuada, massa nec elementum imperdiet, enim arcu fringilla purus, ac bibendum massa augue nec odio. Donec vel hendrerit ligula. Maecenas ante dolor, faucibus tristique commodo non, sollicitudin
    at augue. In lobortis quis est a mattis. Aenean blandit lorem at porta ultrices. Nullam sit amet mauris a justo congue iaculis. Duis urna velit, luctus vel tempus quis, consequat id ex. Etiam accumsan urna ac imperdiet gravida. Etiam gravida rhoncus
    quam sit amet placerat. In tincidunt lorem non lacus semper hendrerit. Phasellus nec ultrices orci.
  </p>
  <p>
    Phasellus sit amet porttitor leo. Phasellus ut eleifend nulla. Morbi luctus odio quis risus aliquam fermentum. Aenean ultrices tortor leo, eu fermentum tortor tincidunt in. Maecenas sodales nisl erat, nec porta tortor mollis non. Donec vulputate non quam
    imperdiet ornare. Integer ex mauris, hendrerit in est sed, sagittis lacinia nulla. Curabitur efficitur dui et neque condimentum, eu lacinia nisi rutrum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Ut vel lorem id justo sodales venenatis. Vestibulum nec mattis risus. Ut a imperdiet lacus, eget molestie dolor. Sed nisl diam, facilisis a nunc non, faucibus suscipit diam. Quisque aliquet, eros sed sodales cursus, ex metus vulputate ante, sagittis dapibus
    leo diam sed ligula. Fusce felis nulla, euismod in facilisis vel, viverra sed eros. Praesent ut diam quis nunc ultrices dignissim et vitae ligula. Donec quam orci, consequat eget leo sit amet, fringilla tempus leo. Nullam felis enim, sodales non lectus
    ut, pretium tincidunt felis. Sed eget odio sit amet nunc consequat vulputate. Vivamus nisl nisl, condimentum vitae malesuada non, tempus ac metus. Nulla placerat arcu eu risus feugiat, efficitur semper diam fringilla. Curabitur et blandit felis. Curabitur
    vel eleifend mi.
  </p>
  <p>
    Maecenas tincidunt mi vestibulum nisi aliquet, at rhoncus mi tristique. Nullam sagittis sed dolor ut aliquet. Sed neque nunc, pulvinar vel ornare id, convallis ut nulla. Integer rhoncus velit non pulvinar commodo. Praesent finibus libero ante, eget venenatis
    augue dignissim id. Nam id odio id ante maximus blandit vel nec purus. Sed eleifend leo ut commodo maximus. Nam pretium a mauris a scelerisque.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis laoreet lorem a nibh dapibus sodales. Curabitur ac orci scelerisque lorem maximus blandit nec ut leo. Nulla feugiat maximus congue. Proin velit leo, suscipit et mollis eu, tempor non eros. Morbi nec mi non lectus auctor fermentum vitae at lectus.
    Sed ut massa sapien. Vivamus eu ipsum quis ante mollis volutpat at ac ipsum. Vivamus ut est sem. Quisque eget nulla posuere sapien rutrum ullamcorper. Donec porta nisl quis quam dignissim elementum sit amet ut turpis. Suspendisse ullamcorper non sapien
    vitae faucibus. Praesent mollis bibendum pretium. Donec auctor lectus nec urna tincidunt egestas vitae vel quam. Sed a neque eleifend, elementum metus quis, sagittis diam. Pellentesque id purus sed nulla euismod tincidunt.
  </p>
</div>
```

If you also need to select the text, you might be able to do so with the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) and [walking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) over every node to find where the match was, but that will be quite tedious to build that, so I leave it as an exercise for now.

Comment: Thanks Kaiido - yes, I'd like to both find and select the text. However, I don't need to use the browser's method, I could very well surround the text with a <span> to highlight the occurrence. In your experience, would Selection API and createTreeWalker be the best options for this approach?

Comment: Yes, that would be the way I'd personally follow for this. If I get more time I may come back to this and give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum you can do is to query for elements and select in between:

```js
findText("first with style"); // true
findText("second"); // true
findText("third"); // true
findMultiple("body p:nth-child(2)","body p:nth-child(4)"); // true

function findText(needle){
  console.log(window.find(needle));
  }
function findMultiple(start,end){

var range = document.createRange();
var root_node = document.body;
range.setStart(root_node.querySelector(start).firstChild, 0);
range.setEnd(root_node.querySelector(end).firstChild, root_node.querySelector(end).innerText.length);
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);

}
```

```html
<p>first<b> with style</b></p>
<p>second</p>
<p>middle</p>
<p>third</p>
```

You could also `querySelect` all elements and check if contains your text, store that element then run the function. But that can be slower, depends.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this solution - [JavaScript window.find doesn't work absolutely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445020/javascript-window-find-doesnt-work-absolutely)

Below solution will give us the boolean value based on the matches of string irrespective of the lines.

I hope you're looking for the below one.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<p>first<b> with style</b></p>
<p>second</p>
<p>third</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    let name = window.name;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Result of matching: "+ containsStr$("second third");
    function containsStr$(str) {
        return $('body:contains("'+str+'")').length > 0;
    }
</script>

</body>
```